# How to convert mmssms.db from android to ios database

Tags: usb, data-transfer, ios

My generell task was to transfer all my sms & mms from my old windows phone to my new iphone.
I found some solution but I'm stuck half way now. It's workaround via android as there seems to be no solution for direct transfer between windows and ios.

What I already got to manage by now using a virtual android device:
transferring all sms and mms via "**contacts and message backup**" from the windows phone and "**sms backup & restore**" to the virtual android device.

But now I'd like to transfer the messages from the virtual android to my iphone.
I wanted to use "**backuptrans**" to do this, but therefor the virtual android has to be plugged to my mac as a usb device. Somehow this seems to be intricate and I didn't manage to do this.

To bypass this problem I tried to copy the mmssms.db or the backup-xml (from sms backup & restore) from the virtual android to my computer and tried to use this as database-file for "backuptrans" directly but this also doesnt seam to work.

My questions:

1. Is there any workaround to make my virtual android device connect to my mac and appear as a working device so that "backuptrans" can use it?
2. Is there a way to transfer the copied mmssms.db-file or the xml-file to a fileformat either backuptrans or my iphone can read as a database file?

I'm using VMware Fusion in macos 10.8 for the virtualization, Android 4.4 in the vm, macos 10.8 or 10.12 for accessing the iphone.